# Are there any Django modules that track all page views without requiring an external connection/library?

Tags: django, analytics

I want something analogous to Google Analytics' tracking, where all page views are tracked automatically, but do not want to rely on 3rd party connections/libraries.  This will be used for a closed-network application, so I can't connect to any external services like Google Analytics.

Additionally, I want this module to track all page views without requiring me to specify manually which should be tracked.

It looks like https://github.com/attuch/django-statistics may be a match, but it doesn't look well-maintained, and the "official" version of project isn't available. Are there any other popular apps that accomplish what I'm looking for?

Comment: You could write a piece of middle ware that simply parses the incoming URL for each request and saves it to a table

Comment: @Dolan, what did you end up using?

Comment: @Jedi -- I forget what we ended up using; it may have been something simple we developed in-house.

Answer (score 0):

There's the Open Source Analytics Platform [PIWIK](http://piwik.org/). The Platform itself is written in PHP, but one could integrate it using the module [django-piwik](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-piwik/). Looks a bit dead, too ... I'd be curious if it still works.